# composit index and possible keys specific query

Tags: index, query-performance, mariadb

i have query like this

```
select
    date_format(referencedate, '%m/%d/%Y') as PostingDate,
    reference_code,
    "" as DocNo,
    Account_Number,
    detail_desc as Description,
    case
        when DEBT_CREDIT = "D" then sum(SF2356896(value_result, 'E77420A8EE606B00', '10011010100010011011', transact_code))
        else 0
    end as Debit,
    case
        when DEBT_CREDIT = "C" then sum(SF2356896(value_result, 'E77420A8EE606B00', '10011010100010011011', transact_code))
        else 0
    end as Credit,
    left(substring_index(COSTCENTER_CODE, "_", 1),
    9) as job,
    mid(substring_index(COSTCENTER_CODE, "_", 1), 10, length(substring_index(COSTCENTER_CODE, "_", 1))) as jobtask
from
    TPYDJOURNALTRANS_INTERCO_EMP
where
    reference_code = '202007'
    and BUSINESS_UNIT = 'XXX'
    and journal_code = 'JMTHOPERATOR'
group by
    reference_code,
    substring_index(COSTCENTER_CODE, "_", 1),
    account_number,
    detail_desc,
    DEBT_CREDIT
```

when i explain this query i got results like this

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: TPYDJOURNALTRANS_INTERCO_EMP
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_BUSINESSUNIT2,idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_journalcode,idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_reference_code,idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_BUSINESSUNIT
          key: idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_BUSINESSUNIT
      key_len: 139
          ref: const,const,const
         rows: 1160572
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

and this index on table TPYDJOURNALTRANS_INTERCO_EMP

```
---------+
| Table                        | Non_unique | Key_name                               | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------------------------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | ix_tuned_transiss_tuned4               |            1 | period_code     | A         |         972 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | ix_tuned_transiss_tuned4               |            2 | processdate     | A         |        2436 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | ix_tuned_transiss_tuned4               |            3 | journal_code    | A         |        2436 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | ix_tuned_transiss_tuned4               |            4 | account_number  | A         |       27269 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | ix_tuned_transiss_tuned4               |            5 | debt_credit     | A         |       20019 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | ix_tuned_transiss_tuned4               |            6 | costcenter_code | A         |      441773 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | ix_tuned_transiss_tuned4               |            7 | detail_desc     | A         |     1656648 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_EMPID          |            1 | EMP_ID          | A         |      125030 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_taxtype        |            1 | tax_type        | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_jobstatuscode  |            1 | jobstatuscode   | A         |          44 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_BUSINESSUNIT2  |            1 | BUSINESS_UNIT   | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_referencedate  |            1 | referencedate   | A         |          14 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_journalcode    |            1 | journal_code    | A         |        4420 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_reference_code |            1 | REFERENCE_CODE  | A         |          14 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_BUSINESSUNIT   |            1 | REFERENCE_CODE  | A         |        4784 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_BUSINESSUNIT   |            2 | BUSINESS_UNIT   | A         |       10370 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp |          1 | idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_BUSINESSUNIT   |            3 | journal_code    | A         |       23922 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------------------------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+------
```

EDIT
this is results from analyze

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "r_loops": 1,
    "r_total_time_ms": 29936,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "x",
      "access_type": "ref",
      "possible_keys": [
        "idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_BUSINESSUNIT2",
        "idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_journalcode",
        "idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_reference_code",
        "idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_BUSINESSUNIT"
      ],
      "key": "idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_BUSINESSUNIT",
      "key_length": "139",
      "used_key_parts": ["REFERENCE_CODE", "BUSINESS_UNIT", "journal_code"],
      "ref": ["const", "const", "const"],
      "r_loops": 1,
      "rows": 1160572,
      "r_rows": 566598,
      "r_total_time_ms": 2402.5,
      "filtered": 100,
      "r_filtered": 100,
      "index_condition": "x.REFERENCE_CODE = '202007' and x.journal_code = 'JMTHOPERATOR' and x.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'ISS'"
    }
  }
}
```

my question is
query on top is effective using composit index `idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_BUSINESSUNIT` because on explain my query using this index ?

and if my query using composit index there is need more single column index or not ?

Comment: good  question.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE tpydjournaltrans_interco_emp` would of partially useful but try to include table structure in further questions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes your `idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_BUSINESSUNIT` index is being used (I assume length 139 corresponds the the length of the three index components).

Other single element index elements may be assisting other queries. For each table reference in a query, a single index is used.

The `idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_BUSINESSUNIT` index corresponds to the 3 elements of the `WHERE` clause.

The `GROUP BY` is causing the sort of ~1M rows returned by the `WHERE` clause so is probably a slow point that isn't using an index.

`COSTCENTER_CODE` seems to be a combination of elements and I recommend using [generated columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/) so either the component or totals an be accessed individually.

Once this is done the `costcenter_code_component`, `account_number`, `detail_desc`, `DEBT_CREDIT` can be appended to the `idx_tpydjournaltrans_ie_BUSINESSUNIT` index to reduce the need to sorts as they are already sorted in the index.

Note at this point your index is getting quite long. Ensure all the columns are to their minimum length and have the smallest character set required.

Comment: thanks for update,
so do yo mean for `costcenter_code` need generate column with value `substring_index` ?

Comment: yes. And use that generated column name in the `group by`, index and the results.

Comment: after me more debug that query, i got this function make slow 
`case
        when DEBT_CREDIT = "D" then sum(SF2356896(value_result, 'E77420A8EE606B00', '10011010100010011011', transact_code))
        else 0
    end as Debit,
    case
        when DEBT_CREDIT = "C" then sum(SF2356896(value_result, 'E77420A8EE606B00', '10011010100010011011', transact_code))
        else 0
    end as Credit`

this function for decrypt data from value_result. this need index too ?

Comment: Without that expression the entire results can come straight from the the index so its not surprising it adds to the query time. Its hard to tell if its the fetching from the main (PK) clustered index is causing the extra time or the the encryption overhead. To  eliminate the former add `value_result, transact_code` to the index to eliminate the PK lookup. Look at `explain` and time differences.

Comment: this example record from field value_result `1E28E1E70227C32206520DED03803DA3`
so may i need index for this field ?

Comment: The inclusion of `value_result` and `transact_code` at the end of the index is to complete the [covering index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) concept. Including only one won't help. The example value isn't that material except that indexes have a fixed length so I hope you are using optimal types and lengths for all the columns in this query.